# Using Keras, how can I input an X_train of images (more than a thousand images)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

My application is accident-avoidance car systems using Machine Learning (Convolutional Neural Networks). My images are 200x100 JPG images and the output is an array of 4 elements: the car would move left, right, stop or move forward. So the output will let one element be `1` (according to the correct action that should be taken) and the 3 other elements will be `0`.

I want to train my machine now in order to help it input any image and decide on the action independently. Here's my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD

import numpy as np

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(16, 1, 1, border_mode='valid', dim_ordering='tf', input_shape=(200, 150, 1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(16, 1, 1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25)) #Cannot take float values

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 1, 1, border_mode='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 1, 1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
# Note: Keras does automatic shape inference.
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=1)
```

How can I input my images (I have them on my PC)? And how can I specify the Y-train?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider Debugging. Also see [mcve] and [homework](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 10):

This Keras blog post, [Building powerful image classification models using very little data](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html), is an excellent tutorial for training a model on images stored in directories.  It also introduces the `ImageDataGenerator` class, which has the member function `flow_from_directory` referenced in @isaac-moore's answer.  `flow from directory` can be used train on images, where the directory structure is used to deduce the value of `Y_train`.

The three python scripts that accompany the tutorial blog post can be found at the links below:

1. [classifier_from_little_data_script_1.py](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d)
2. [classifier_from_little_data_script_2.py](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/f35fbc80e066a49d65f1688a7e99f069)
3. [classifier_from_little_data_script_3.py](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/7eb39b44eb9e16e59632d25fb3119975)

(Of course, these links are in the blog post itself, but the links are not centrally located.)  Note that scripts 2 and 3 build on the output of the previous.  Also, note that additional files will need to be downloaded from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data) and [Github](https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link, it helped me.

Answer (score 5):

Create a folder for train and in the folder, create separate folders for the classes of images.

Access the images using

```
  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train',
    target_size=(150, 150),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')
```

In reference to [keras.io](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

Comment: Try to provide a well-formatted, documented and detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this repository you have an example:

https://github.com/ZFTurbo/KAGGLE_DISTRACTED_DRIVER/blob/master/run_keras_simple.py

They have different folders, in every folder there is a different class of image. They load the images using OpenCV and they build arrays that contains the class of every image.