# How Can I Load My Own Images Instead Of Mnist Dataset Images?

Tags: python, keras, dataset, mnist

Hi I am very frustrated that all the ml examples I see only use the MNIST dataset and don't use custom images and I would like to load in my own image dataset of pokemon. Here is my code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""autoencoder.ipynb

Automatically generated by Colaboratory.

Original file is located at
    https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1P5rdEhs3lzcNMK9SWsOXdNq9nl74E54D
"""

from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

# this is the size of our encoded representations
encoding_dim = 32  # 32 floats -> compression of factor 24.5, assuming the input is 784 floats

# this is our input placeholder
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
# "encoded" is the encoded representation of the input
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input_img)
# "decoded" is the lossy reconstruction of the input
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

# this model maps an input to its encoded representation
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
# create a placeholder for an encoded (32-dimensional) input
encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
# retrieve the last layer of the autoencoder model
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
# create the decoder model
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=10,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))

# encode and decode some digits
# note that we take them from the *test* set
encoded_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)

# use Matplotlib (don't ask)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10  # how many digits we will display
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 4))
for i in range(n):
    # display original
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # display reconstruction
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + 1 + n)
    plt.imshow(decoded_imgs[i].reshape(28, 28))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Here is the structure of my images

```
images
  |_____abomasnow
        |___image
  |_____abra
        |___image
  |_____absol
        |___image
  |_____accelgor
        |___image
  ...
  |_____zweilous
        |___image
  |_____zubat
        |___image
  |_____zorua
        |___image
```

I've tried using [convert_to_mnist_format](https://github.com/Arlen0615/Convert-own-data-to-MNIST-format) but I got:
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (120,120,3) into shape (120,120,4)

So I would like some help to make [this](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Tb7Rwek4cdl8WmIuVz_i6KZDn_s51BIC?usp=sharing) dataset able to be read by the Autoencoder above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Keras, how can I input an X\_train of images (more than a thousand images)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466303/using-keras-how-can-i-input-an-x-train-of-images-more-than-a-thousand-images)

Comment: Your directory structure is perfect for using `ImageDataGenerator` with `flow_from_directory`. Take a quick look at the docs with these terms and you will probably find a good solution.

Comment: I think you should try "convolutional" networks, a Dense network may work with tiny and simple mnist images, but will not be good for Pokemon (or any complex images problem).

Comment: The error message you got seems to be a conflict between images with 4 channels (RGBA) and images with 3 channels (RGB).